# CakePHP 1.2 - Model validation database table field prefixed with id

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.2

Inspect the **'Qty'** form input with Firebug

```
<input id "Item0Quantity">
```

I am having difficult validating this element produced by this code:

```
<?php echo $form->input("Item.$id.quantity.", array('label' => 'Qty', 'class' => 'txt'));?>
```

I am working with a form input element that is prefixed with the database **table name (Item)** and a **unique id**, the reason for this is to add some JavaScript functionality. Though it still needs CakePHP validation on the **Item model**.

Here is the **input form element** that needs to be validated:

```
<?php echo $form->input("Item.$id.quantity.", array('label' => 'Qty', 'class' => 'txt'));?>
```

So how will the will be written in the **items model**? My attempt:

```
 'Item.$id.quantity' => array(           
    'rule' => 'numeric',         
    'allowEmpty' => true,
    'message' => 'quanitity mut be numeric'
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

The validation will look the same, still by just the field name:

```
'quantity' => array(           
    'rule' => 'numeric',         
    'allowEmpty' => true,
    'message' => 'quanitity mut be numeric'
),
```

When you use `saveAll` Cake will iterate through each Item and validate it accordingly.